# Android - Animation speed not same across devices

Tags: android, animation, vector, svg-animate

I am working on the `VectorAnimation` to animate multiple paths in a SVG. I have given the `duration` as 100 for each animation. But when I run the animation in different devices, the speed is not the same. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code please

Comment: Have you figured out the problem ,I have the same issue ,but I think its device related.Because I tried on different screens and the speed was ok .

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in Developer options "Animator duration scale",by default this value is 1x if they are different for devices then you may experience slower or faster animations based on value set.

Comment: aah I have checked in all the devices where all the value is set to 1x.  I have read in another link that we need to have different animation duration for different screen densities. Do you have any idea about it? @Akshay Shetty

Comment: May I know if your animation is choppy or too fast on devices that you are testing?? I too have noticed such absurd behaviour and also could you post code used to achieve vector drawable animation